# How to stop CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser from following links

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

Right now we use the old WPF `WebBrowser` control to show a web site in our program. Since this old control is based on Internet Explorer 11 and a lot of newer web sites show a message, that they are not running on Internet Explorer 11, we are looking for a replacement for this old control.

We took a look into `WebView2` but unfortunately this browser doesn't show up in our setup (WPF control hosted in an `ElementHost` in WinForms, hosted in an ocx in COM, used in MS Access).

So we take a look in `CefSharp` now. I didn't get to trying if this browser shows up in our setup because I don't find a solution for a simple requirement in my test program.

I'd like to restrict the user to follow links that might be part of the web site. In `WebView2` there's a `NavigationStarting` event which can be canceled, but I didn't find anything like that in `CefSharp`.

There's an `AddressChanged` event, but this also fires when the web site is re-directing.

So, is it somehow possible with `CefSharp` to load an initial website (including any re-directions) and then doing nothing when a link inside the web site is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel navigation in [OnBeforeBrowse](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/101.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestHandler_OnBeforeBrowse.htm)

```cs
public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        if (request.TransitionType == TransitionType.LinkClicked)
        {
            //Cancel the request by returning true 
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnBeforeBrowse(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, frame, request, userGesture, isRedirect);
    }
}

browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```

Comment: Thank you. I read about "OnBeforeBrowse" but I looked for it as an event of the browser control...